# How to allow webapp authentication to facebook while blocking www.facebook.com?

Tags: facebook, authentication, web-applications

How to allow webapp authentication to facebook while blocking www.facebook.com?

Company is using a SAAS webapp that is using facebook for authentication.  But we cannot allow access to www.facebook.com